# How to Add a Reference to a Web Service in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, api, web-services

Is it possible to add Web reference in NodeJS project as [we do in .NET framework Web API Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)? Basically NodeJS API project will act as a middleware between Front End and XML Web service.XML Web service is kinda secured third party service which we want to integrate in our NodeJS projects.Configuring & Integrating web service in C# Web API project is very easy but in NodeJS its bit tricky it seems.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish **exactly** by adding a reference in a NodeJS project? What interaction between the NodeJS project and the ASMX service are you trying to achieve/implement? You need to update your question with more details.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Updated the question. please have a look

Comment: When I create a service reference in .NET WCF, the ServiceModel Metadata utility tool scans the contract to automatically create a very helpful "wrapper" client class for me. Then, I can call my REST methods with typesafe and intellisense supported one liners like:
"int squareOfThree = calcClient.Square(3);" 
or 
"bool success = accountClient.Deposit(1000.00);"
In contrast, using the Fetch NPM package to make those same calls in Node.js or React.js requires several lines of code that are not typesafe and don't support intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add references directly like you do in .Net; however, there are a number of node_modules which support integration with 3rd party services. For example (given that you mentioned XML), this module ([node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap)) takes a .wsdl file and generates a SOAP api wrapper.